# How to get the SQL statement from a Sequel model

Tags: ruby, sequel

Is there a way to get JUST the SQL statement from a [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/ClassMethods.html) model?

```
class Asset < Sequel::Model(:Asset)
  set_primary_key :id

  many_to_one :site,    key: :siteid
  many_to_one :company, key: :companyid

  def validate
    super
    errors.add(:partnumber, "can't be empty") if partnumber.nil? || partnumber.empty?
    errors.add(:serialnumber, "can't be empty") if serialnumber.nil? || serialnumber.empty?
    errors.add(:description, "can't be empty") if description.nil? || description.empty?
  end
end

asset = Asset.new
# Add values to asset

puts asset.insert_sql
```

Comment: Use the Sequel console to open a connection to your database, and mess around with the resulting IRB session to try appending `.sql` to variations in the Sequel cheatsheet. It's fascinating to see how you can build your queries and to see how well Sequel creates the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
puts Asset.dataset.insert_sql
```

to actually insert (defaulted) values.

or

```
puts Asset.dataset.insert_sql(asset.values)
```

if you already have a prepared instance. Not sure if you had that in mind?

See [Sequel::Dataset](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jeremyevans/sequel/Sequel/Dataset) documentation and [Sequel's mass assignment guide](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/mass_assignment.rdoc) for more.

Comment: The second line `Asset.dataset.insert_sql(asset)` is the snippet that meets my requirements. Thank you.